# Can't get VimClojure to talk to NGServer

Tags: clojure, leiningen, nailgun, vimclojure

I'm trying to setup Vim as a Clojure programming environment, using these instructions:

http://naleid.com/blog/2011/12/19/getting-a-clojure-repl-in-vim-with-vimclojure-nailgun-and-leiningen/

I'm able to start `ng-server` from the root of a Leiningen project. But whenever I try to start a repl in vim, I get:

```
; Use \p to close this buffer!

VimClojure could not initialise the server connection.
That means you will not be able to use the interactive features.
Reasons might be that the server is not running or that there is
some trouble with the classpath.

VimClojure will *not* start the server for you or handle the classpath.
There is a plethora of tools like ivy, maven, gradle and leiningen,
which do this better than VimClojure could ever do it.
```

I have `VimClojure` plugin installed and added these lines to my `.vimrc` file:

```
let vimclojure#NailgunClient = "~/bin/ng"
let vimclojure#WantNailgun = 1

let g:clj_highlight_builtins=1      " Highlight Clojure's builtins
let g:clj_paren_rainbow=1           " Rainbow parentheses'!
```

`RainbowParens` is working and I can get a response from `ng` on the command line.

I also tried `slime.vim`. While it works, it takes a full 5 seconds to respond to a simple `(+ 2 3)` typed in `vim`, which is rather annoying.

Help?